# How can I use the new URL API to get request details?

Tags: node.js, url, node-modules

After following a tutorial on Node.js I tried to get the details of a request like so:

```
const url = require('url');

http
    .createServer((req, res) => {
        *let parsedUrl = url.parse(req.url, true);*
        
        res.write('---------->  ');
        res.write(parsedUrl.search);
        res.write(parsedUrl.search);
        re.write(parsedUrl.pathname);
        res.write('  <----------');
        res.end();
    })
    .listen(3000, () => cl('Listening on port 3000.'));
```

This is working fine but I get a warning that `url.parse()` is deprecated and instead I should use `new URL()` API. But the problem is that with `url.parse()` I can pass the `req.url` as parameter whereas with `new URL()` I have to pass a string as parameter, therefore I can't use `req.url` to get the request details. Or is something I'm missing?

```
http
    .createServer((req, res) => {
        *let myUrl = new URL(req.url.toString());*
        
        res.write(myUrl);
        res.end();
    })
    .listen(3000, () => cl('Listening on port 3000.'));
```

If  curl this URL `curl http://localhost:3000/test?hello=world`, I get this error `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL: /test?hello=world`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
import http from "node:http"
import { URL } from "node:url"

const PORT = 3000

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  const url = new URL(`http://${req.headers.host}${req.url}`)
  return res.end(url.href)
})

server.listen(PORT, () => `Server is running on port ${PORT}`)
```